# Some issues with python, python2.7 and python3 in Kali Linux

Tags: python, linux, scripting

I want to run a python program but I got this message:

```
"SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file windows-exploit-suggester.py on line 1291, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details"
```

I tried with python, python2.7 and python3. I am using Kali Linux. Tried commenting this line but still having issues.

Also I am having problems with xlrd library. I installed in many ways (pip, pip3, apt) it show me that the requeriment is satisfied but I am not able to run it. Is an old script.

```
[-] please install and upgrade the python-xlrd library
```

Answer (score 0):

for python3 :

```
pip3 install python-xlrd
```

for python2 :

```
pip install python-xlrd
```